# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are:

Tags: c#, sockets, serversocket

To begin with, I'm a student, don't scold me too much for my code, I'm trying to get better.
I will accept any criticism about the code, it helps to get better)

The crux of my problem: when the server is disconnected, I send a command to it, process it, and send a response from the server stating that it has completed its work, in my second project (client) I receive a message and process it, and sometimes it is processed, and sometimes it happens the problem is that I just get an exception.
And it comes out of nothing, the server shutdown function works, I have to display a MessageBox, and it immediately switches me to another function and receives an exception for converting a byte to an object (the function works correctly, all other commands work without problems).
I have already climbed all the Internet resources, nothing helps.

Where does the exception occur

```
 public Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
        {
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
                memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                object obj = binForm.Deserialize(memStream);***//ERROR HERE  System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are:***
                return obj;
            }
        }
```

The start of an exception occurs in this function after receiving a message from the server before or during the display of the MessageBox
at this moment it switches me to this function and catches an exception

```
private  void DisconnectServer()
        {
            try
            {
                string theMessage = "Клиент выполнил дисконнект"; 
                byte[] msg = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(theMessage); 
                int bytesSent = sock.Send(msg);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRec = sock.Receive(bytes);
                string msgserv = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                //MessageBox.Show("Сервер (" + sock.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + ") ответил: " + msgserv);
                sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both); 
                sock.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Клиент: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The moment the server message is sent to the client about the disconnection and after which an error occurs

```
 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.WriteLine(client + ":" + data);
                            Console.ResetColor();
                            string theReply = "Сервер остановлен";
                            byte[] msg = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(theReply);
                            handler.Send(msg);
                            choice = 0;
                            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                            handler.Close();
                            break;
```

Comment: *"my code is not worth scolding"* - we will be the judge of that ;)

Comment: You've tagged this UDP, but the connection usage here suggest that this is TCP; please can you clarify: is this TCP or UDP? it matters ***a lot***  (oh: as a side note: any time you use `Encoding.Default`, the code is basically broken; don't ever use that; if even remotely in doubt: `Encoding.UTF8`; so much so that in recent versions of .NET, `Encoding.Default` *now means* `Encoding.UTF8`, but it didn't used to; it used to *basically* mean `Encoding.Random` (although to be fair, the randomness was well-defined and predictable))

Comment: @MarcGravell Using TCP.

Comment: @AlexanderKhurnov I've removed the udp tag, then; right: from these two lines: `int bytesRec = sock.Receive(bytes);` and `string msgserv = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);`, I am already basically almost entirely sure that the problem is "message framing" (or the lack of it); you can basically never just call .Read/Receive and think "I can decode that data now" - that's just not how TCP works; you need to frame data so you know where each message starts and ends, and only when you've buffered an entire message can you process it (also taking care not to discard data from the ...

Comment: ...next frame - keeping it buffered); I discuss this in more detail in the "Network packets: what you send is not (usually) what you get" section, here: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html; and to be fair: this is a very common mistake - see (from a few days ago, it wasn't aimed at, or inspired by, this question): https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/1448180422094041088

Comment: As a general recommendation, I would suggest avoiding BinaryFormatter whenever possible. It is slow, inefficient, insecure and has poor backward/forward compatibility. I would suggest taking a look at other serialization libraries/formats, like protobuf.net or json.net.